# Understanding 2's complement multiplication using Booth's algorithm

Tags: multiplication

I was referring Booth's algorithm for 2's complement multiplication from William Stallings book. It was explained as follows (please ignore two starting words "As before", it still makes complete sense):

> [image]
>   [image]

The author then gives following example for $7\times 3$, which I am able to understand:

> [image]

Next author gives examples for all combinations of +ve and -ve combination of multiplication:

[image]

**Doubt**

I am not able to get how example in figure 9.13 maps to same example but more compact approach illustrated in figure 9.14(a). I mean how those entries are made in fig 9.14 (a)

**PS**: Wanted to add tags "booths-algorithm" and "2s-complement-multiplication", but wasnt able to create those due to low reputations.

Answer (score 1):

So, it goes like this, we have **Q = 0011** and **Q<sub>-1</sub> = 0** in the beginning.

At the start, we have

> **count = 4**
> **(Q<sub>0</sub> Q<sub>-1</sub>) = (1 0)**

so we perform the **A←(A-M)** operation, according to the figure each time when we perform any operation in **register A**, we assume that its value is **00000000** for **+M** and **11111111** for **−M**. Performing **A←(A-M)** yields the first partial product

> **A = 11111111+00001001 = 11111001**

Now, we have

> **count = 3**
> **(Q<sub>0</sub> Q<sub>−1</sub>) = (1 1)**

note here, when we have **(Q<sub>0</sub> Q<sub>−1</sub>)** as **(1 1)** or **(0 0)**, we'll just skip and put *all 0s* in the partial product by shifting it by 1 bit to the left (as we do in multiplication) as it's done in the book, which is the 2nd partial product

> **A = 00000000+00000000 = 00000000**
> shifting it left by 1 bit, **00000000**

Now, we have

> **count = 2**
> **(Q<sub>0</sub> Q<sub>−1</sub>) = (0 1)**

so we perform the **(A←A+M)** operation, which gives us the 3rd partial product

> **A = 00000000+00000111 = 00000111**
> shifting it left by 2 bits, **00011100**

Now, we have

> **count = 1**
> **(Q<sub>0</sub> Q<sub>−1</sub>) = (0 0)**

as mentioned above, we'll just skip and put all 0s as the 4th partial product

> **A = 00000000+00000000 = 00000000**
> shifting it left by 3 bits, **00000000**
> `(this isn't illustrated in the figure 9.14(a))`

after this operation **count = 0** and then we'll sum up all the partial products as

```
   11111001 (1st partial product)
   00000000 (2nd partial product)
   00011100 (3rd partial product)
 + 00000000 (4th partial product)
-------------------
   00010101 (final product)
```

As we all know (00010101)<sub>2</sub> = (21)<sub>10</sub>. That's what done in the **figure 9.14(a)**, but shown in a different (**or COMPACT**) way as

```
   11111001
   0000000
 + 000111
-------------------
   00010101
```

Well, you can make it more compact like this:-

```
   11111001
 + 000111
-------------------
   00010101
```

But all of 'em will give you the binary representation of 21.